# Ektron user change password?

Tags: content-management-system, asp.net-membership, membership, ektron

I have a Ektron client with Ektron installed.  They would like to add the functionality to change a password to something they want.  Do I need to be concerned with the ektron part or just go ahead and make my edit?

Is there an easy way to do that?  Any links to information would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're talking about Ektron CMS400 Membership Users, you can use the Web Service Method:

[User.ResetMembershipUserPassword](http://www.ektron.com/manuals/cms400/v76/API_Help/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=%21%21OVERLOADED_ResetMembershipUserPassword_Ektron_Services_User.html)

If you're trying to set it for regular CMS400 users, you're out of luck. The administrator will need to reset their password (if they've forgotten it) and the user will need to log back in to the workarea and change their password there.

UPDATE

That method resets the password to a random value. To set the password to a desired value, you'll have to use:

**Ektron.Cms.BusinessApi.dll**

```
Ektron.Cms.UserAPI.ResetMembershipUserPassword(string Username, 
                                               string oldPassword, 
                                               string newPassword)
```

Comment: Will the user be able to set the password to what they would like or will it auto generate a password?  I would like to set it manually if possible.

Thank You for your help.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your help.  This will get me going down the right path.

Thanks Again!