# Ektron member to change password

Tags: ektron

Ektron 8.0.1 SP1

I found this solution ([Ektron user change password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/912507/ektron-user-change-password)) but it appears to be for a different version of Ektron.

On my site, the members accounts were set up for them and I am using a custom profile page to allow them to change their information.  The last piece is allowing them to change their password to one of their choosing.  I tried searching the old Ektron forums but the search features seems to be broken/disabled.

Anyone have the right code?

Answer (score 1):

I stopped looking for a specific API call to change the password and found some code I was using elsewhere to get the UserData, change it and save it back.  This worked perfect so I thought I'd share.

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _UserApi = new Ektron.Cms.API.User.User();
    if (_UserApi.UserId > 0)
    {
        _UserData = _UserApi.GetActiveUser(_UserApi.UserId, false);
    }
}

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    // put validation code here

    try
    {
        _UserData.Password = txtPassword.Text.Trim();
        _UserApi.UpdateUser(_UserData);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // handle
    }
}
```